# Screen Blinking Issue During Android Activity Transitions With Shared Elements

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, mobile-application

Experiencing screen blinking during Android activity transitions when going from splash screen to login page, but weirdly enough not from login to register page:

[image]

Is there any way to fix this issue ?

I have seen several other solutions such as:

- getWindow().setEnterTransition(null);
  getWindow().setExitTransition(null);
- "*overridePendingTransition(0, 0)*" after the "finish()" statement in the splash screen code.
- https://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-5/

Below is my Java code for the splash screen activity activity switch and animation:

```
// on below line we are calling handler to run a task
        // for specific time interval
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, signIn.class);
               // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);


                // Get the shared element (the View) that will be transitioned between activities
                View sharedElement = findViewById(R.id.logoView);

                // Create the transition animation options
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(SplashScreen.this,
                        Pair.create(sharedElement,"shared_logo_transition"));

                // Start the new activity with the transition animation
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());


                finish();
                //overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Have you tried removing Handler? You just need to use setEnterTransition and setExitTransition. I'm not sure how Handler works on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static Activity activity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        activity = this;

    }
}



public class signIn extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (SplashScreen.activity != null) {
            finish();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).